# Find dynamic length number from string using XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have input XML like below

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <param>:22:/ABC/GID:50749612002 BOOK USER REF: 12311111112222 XYZ: DEF BK ID:3333 3333 JKL:MNN - VZXVXHFHF DETA ABC:DEF ORDERID:989796123456789.GKLT C:0006789 FASDFSF.FYRTY 53546475</param>
  </root>
```

Need help to extract ORDERID using XSLT.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Well, you have tagged this as [tag:xslt-2.0] and [tag:regex] so it shouldn't be so difficult to use the functions in XSLT/XPath 2.0 like `tokenize` or `matches` supporting regular expressions or the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction introduced in XSLT 2 to use regular expressions. So make use of them and tell us how it failed if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider extracting the node value to a variable `$param`:

```
<xsl:variable name="param">
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/param"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now you can use since XSLT 2.0 the function [`replace`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html) to get the number:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($param, '.*?ORDERID:(\d+)\.\w{4} .*', '$1')"/>
```

The regex `.*?ORDERID:(\d+)\.\w{4} .*` is demonstrated at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2TpwU7/1/).